# Including a specific file which is already `--exclude`d in the `tar` command line

Tags: command-line, 22.04, backup, tar

I want to backup some directories using `tar`. However, there are some sub-directories that I want to skip.

So, my command line is something like this:

```
cd /
tar \
  --exclude=thisdir  --exclude=thatdir  \
  --exclude=logs     --exclude=tmp      \
  -czf "$backup_file" \
  etc  \
  home
```

Now, I want to include into the archive a specific file named `/home/my_user/logs/important.log`.

What option can I add to the above command to make it so?

Please, note that I am not asking for alternative commands or `bash` scripting. I want to know if there is a method, by using *only* `tar` (version 1.34).

Comment: There is no `--include` option in `tar`.

Comment: Pity (was a guess) and now I am at home:  you can pass an arbitrary list of files for tar to archive from stdin using -files-from  See https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html

Comment: Putting the `--files-from=-` option after the `--exclude` options did not work. But, putting it before, _did_! Thanks for the suggestion! I used `ls home/my_user/logs/important.log* | tar --files-from=.` ... Please, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the `--add-file=...` option — when put **before** the `--exclude` options — will solve my problem. So, the command line should be something like this:

```
cd /
tar \
  --add-file=home/my_user/logs/important.log  \
  --exclude=thisdir  --exclude=thatdir  \
  --exclude=logs     --exclude=tmp      \
  -czf "$backup_file" \
  etc  \
  home
```